# Wordpress front end Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, plugins, frontend

I'm currently developing a plugin that renders it's own pages so the form submissions for the admin occur outside of the admin panel. I would like to create instant updates on form submission like you see in the Wordpress admin panel.

For example:

I would like a form to add a contact.
The form asks for "Contact Name", "Contact Type", "Contact Number" and a hidden field of "Job ID". I would like to load all contacts already in the database for this job and I would like it to refresh when you add a new contact.

JS:

```
    jQuery(document).on("click", "#submitcontact", function(e){
   
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "tm_add_contact",
            contactname: jQuery("#contactname").val(),
            contacttype: jQuery("#contacttype").val(),
            contact: jQuery("#contact").val(),
            jobnumber: jQuery("#jobnumber").val()
        },
        success: function(data){
           alert("success " + data);
        },
        error: function(e){
             alert("error " + e);
        }
    });
   
});
```

Form:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-toggle="popover" title="Add Contact" data-placement="left" data-html='true' data-content='
                            <form>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contactname">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactname" name="contactname" placeholder="Jane Doe">
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contacttype">Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="contacttype" name="contacttype">
                                  <option>Landline</option>
                                  <option>Mobile</option>
                                  <option>Buisness</option>
                                  <option>Email</option>
                                  <option>Fax</option>
                                </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contact">Contact</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name=contact placeholder="">
                                <input type="hidden" id="jobnumber" name="jobnumber" value="<?php echo $job->JobNumber ?>">
                              </div>
                              <button type="button" id="submitcontact" name="submitcontact" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Contact</button>
                            </form>   
                                '><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Contact</button>
```

Function:

```
    function tm_add_contact(){

$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];
$contacttype = $_POST['contacttype'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$jobnumber = $_POST['jobnumber'];
$date = current_time( 'mysql' );
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'trademanager_job_contacts';
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'JobNumber' => $jobnumber,
        'ContactName' => $contactname,
        'Type' => $contacttype,
        'Contact' => $contact,
        'DateAdded' => $date
    ),
    array(
        '%s'
    )
);

echo "HELLO WORLD!!!";

die();
return true;
}
//
add_action('tm_ajax', 'tm_add_contact'); // Call when user logged in
add_action('tm_ajax', 'tm_add_contact'); // Call when user in not logged in
```

I was using the wrong actions above and the incorrect names. The form now works, however I still do not understand how to show results on submission without refreshing the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ajaxForm jquery plugin.
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm

Afterwards using a callback:

```
function showResponse(response){
      jQuery('.datalist > tbody').prepend(response);
}
```

Note: format the response in backend accordingly using tables. You can even clear the form after a successful submittion.

Or without ajaxForm plugin:

```
jQuery('form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var form = $(this);
   // than use $.ajax

    $.post(url,data,function(response){            
        jQuery('.your_table > tbody').append(response);
        //using previously defined form variable, because this is now post object
        form[0].reset();

    });
   // or use: return false
});
```

For database results use

```
$db_contacts = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY id');
```

Then:

```
foreach($db_contacts as $contact){
   echo $contact->contactname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roman but I am trying to avoid using another plugin, also I am very much interested in learning how this works.

Comment: Hi, currently answring by phone, so i can't write all the code. Hope it helps anyway. If you want POST variables defined all at once use extract(). Then $varname ;) just a hint.

Comment: I saw the wrong actions but i thought you were hooking on your custom one. You have to change button type submit to work then hookinto the onsubmit event on the form. Then on response you just return the missing part and append it. On successful insertion return the posted record.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help Roman. I did upvote your answer but I am too new apparently... Do you have any advice on submitting a form with multiple inputs with the same name/id? the name, as an example is an array so input_name[] ...

Comment: Have to ask. Is the code working? Yes, you can use it like that... Input_name[contactname]. The ID attribute has to be unique so avoid using too much ids, use classes instead ( .class_name ). Then you catch it in PHP depending on the form method (post,get). $_REQUEST[input_name]. The approach is cleaner. If you use just input_name[] (array data type), you get only indexes like 0,1,2,3

Comment: If you want to validate input fields in frontend is a bit more complicated. You have to iterate each field, checking values. For now use required attribute on desired input fields. It's a HTML5 only. Not for older browsers.

Comment: Oh. Wordpress action has to be in ajax url so it's a GET variable.

Comment: It's working, but only for 3 inputs, any more and it just ignores them...

Comment: This should not happen. It's name attribute defined on rest of the fields?

Comment: Or you have different names. Output $_REQUEST on ajax call. you should get all of them.